# Is it safe to use Facebook Connect or other 3rd party for a web login?

Tags: facebook, authentication, openid

I'm considering the best way to implement the login for users of a new app I am developing. My concern with using facebook connect or some other 3rd party for login is that I am afraid that I will then be at the mercy of those sites.

What if Facebook decides to start charging for Facebook Connect? What if they decide they don't want to let my users log in anymore (for WHATEVER reason).

My concern is...If my 3rd party login servicer suddenly goes away or makes life difficult, am I suddenly out of business?

Comment: "My concern is...If my 3rd party login servicer suddenly goes away or makes life difficult, am I suddenly out of business?" --- store some information that will be able to identify user. Say - email.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook will never charge for the login possibility. There are so many other options (like Open-ID and stuff) that are for free, so they would lose a lot of people.

If you are unsure, use the Registration Plugin instead. It is much better and you are allowed to store the data you gain with it. For example, according to the Facebook rules you are not allowed to just store the email of the user just because he accepted the email permission. You have to tell him that you will store it, and he has to be able to change it (in a textfield, for example) before you store it. It´s not that simple with the Data Policy.

There you go: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/